# React TypeScript Change route programmatically with BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Im using `BrowserRouter` to manage the routing. I have a function that when its called I want to change the route without a page refresh.

```
import React from 'react';
const myPage: React.FC = (props) => {
  function loadPage(event: any) {
    if (event.target.id) {
      window.history.push('/' + event.target.id)
    }
  return (
    <div id='home' onClick={loadPage}><div/>
    <section> {props.children} </section>
  )
...
```

The error im getting is `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'History'.ts(2339)`

**Note**: the router is a child of this element and is being passed into props.children

Answer (score 1):

There is no function push on history object in window. I suggest you use react-router-dom's history or Redirect.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const myPage: React.FC = (props) => {
  function loadPage(event: any) {
    if (event.target.id) {
      props.history.push('/' + event.target.id)
    }
  return (
    <div id='home' onClick={loadPage}><div/>
  )
```

then at the end, you should wrapp your component before exporting it in withRouter component

```
export default withRouter(myPage);
```

Wrapping it like this will make history accessible through props

Comment: im getting an error `Module '"../../../../../../Users/myComp/Documents/myProject/node_modules/@types/react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'history'.ts(2305)`

Comment: thanks for the help, the error I get with the changes is now `Property 'history' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Could you console.log props to see what is going on there? You should be able to see history there and also location.

Comment: Ok. It says here that the type of your component is BrowserRouter which was not visible through your code example. You do not need to wrap this component in BrowserRouter since you can do what you want without it. I suggest you go to the official docs of react router dom and check there what is it that you need exactly. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198726/discussion-between-lazar-nikolic-and-bill).

Answer (score 0):

If the `myPage` component is being passed as a prop to the `<Route>`component for eg: `<Route exact path="/myPage" component={myPage}>` then you could use the React-Router props that are received by the `myPage` component for navigation.

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

const myPage: React.FC = (props:RouteComponentProps) => {
  function loadPage(event: any) {
    if (event.target.id) {
      props.history.push('/' + event.target.id)
    }
  return (
    <div id='home' onClick={loadPage}><div/>
  )
```

Comment: im getting the error `Type '(props: RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>': history, location, matchts(2322)`

Comment: @Bill You can fix it by adding Type parameter to the `React.FC` type `const myPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props:RouteComponentProps) => {`

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked was...

```
window.location.href = '/'+event.target.id;
```